# How to mock method of testing class

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

How to mock method of testig class?

For example:

```
class Test {

publick String mainMethod() {
String test = methdotWhichNeedMock("Hello", "World");
return test;
}
public String methodtWhichNeedMock(String s1, String s2) {
return s1 + s2;
}

}
```

i tried to use

```
when(test.methdotWhichNeedMock(s1 , s2)).thenReturn("result");
```

and many constructions like doThen..., but every try my programm doing logic of methdotWhichNeedMock method.

My TestClass:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestClass {
    @InjectMocks
    Test service;

    @Test
    void mainMethod() {
        when(service.methodtWhichNeedMock("s1", "s2")).thenReturn("new String");
        assertEquals("new String", service.mainMethod());
    }
}
```

What should I do so that the logic of the methodtWhichNeedMock method doesn't execute, but just returns what I write in thenReturn when I try to call it?

Comment: How your test class looks like?

Comment: Calling the class under test `Test` is rather confusing.

Answer (score 0):

use `@Spy` if you want to mock a class partially:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestClass {
    @Spy
    Test service;

    @Test
    void mainMethod() {
        when(service.methodtWhichNeedMock("s1", "s2")).thenReturn("new String");
        assertEquals("new String", service.mainMethod());
    }
}
```

So for all methods that are not mocked, the real code will be executed, for the rest the mock will be executed